# Angular.io v8: animate object and query()-children simple and together

Tags: angular, animation, angular-animations

#### I lack some understanding, how Angular.io (V8) animation works:

**I want to animate a base object *and* its children:**

[image]

#### https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yrxvby

```html
<div class="wrap"
    [@anim1]="anim1" [@anim2]="anim2"
    (@anim1.start)="onAnimationEvent($event)"
    (@anim1.done)="onAnimationEvent($event)"
>
    <button [class.active]="anim1" (click)="toggleAnim1()">Anim 1</button>
    <button [class.active]="anim2" (click)="toggleAnim2()">Anim 2</button>

    <hr>
    <b class='b'>B</b>
    <b class='b'>B</b>
    <b class='b'>B</b>
    <b class='b'>B</b>
</div>
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, transition, group, query, style, animate, keyframes, state } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('anim1', [
      state('true', style({
        border: '10px solid pink',
        backgroundColor: 'purple',
      })),
      state('false', style({
        border: '10px solid lime',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
      })),
      transition('true => false', [
        animate('1s linear')
      ]),
      transition('false => true', [
        animate('.2s linear')
      ]),
    ]),
    trigger('anim2', [
      transition('* => false', [
        query('b', animate( 1000, style({ border: '12px solid cyan' })))
      ]),
      transition('* => true', [
        query('b', animate( 1000, style({ border: '4px solid red' })))
      ]),
    ])
  ] // animations
})
export class AppComponent {
  anim1 = false;
  anim2 = false;

  toggleAnim1() {
    this.anim1 = !this.anim1;
  }

  toggleAnim2() {
    this.anim2 = !this.anim2;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

- **animating the base object basically works:** purple-ish to green-ish and back (triggered by a status change triggered by a button)
- **animating the contained `<b>` tags however does not work as expected:** Sure, for the time of the transition the color changes (to red-ish resp. blue-ish colors), but before and after it abruptly snaps back to the default color (white border around).

So, it's neithing coming from nor going to its final animation state, so-to-speak.
**What am I doing wrong?**

I did notice, that I put the b-styles within a query within transition (based on stuff I have seen), **is there a way, to put them inside a `state()` ?**

Can I combine the main-object animation (anim1) and child animation (anim2)? (In the most simple, toggle-forth-and-back-style way. *One variable to forth-and-back 'em all*...)

I did notice, that upon reload also the main object sometimes has its (prior-to-animation) css base colors briefly appearing...

If I could I would indeed want to start on *everything* with the `.css`-defined colors, thus only have to specify “the other state” (the active one) within the component source, avoiding to replicating the css Styles for “back-to-normal”. **Is that possible?**

Should I maybe not start with `false` but with undefined, and/or do something (grouped?) along the lines of `* <=> true, false <=> true` ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve it as you thought.
There is a limitation between the Parent > child relation.
Please see this ticket: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18775

The recommended way to achieve this is the following:
Add a `@child` to each element and specify it's end state

`<span [@child]="{value:'yes/no', params: { opacity: 0.5 }}"></span>`

Comment: ...but [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/animations/query) „brags“ about being able to animate the children at the same time. - That's the whole point of the `query()`-function, no? [Perhaps there is a misunderstanding about my casual use of the word „state“ in the question: I do not truly want to change any Component's state, I just want to have one „CSS normal definition“ (in the .css/.scss-file), and one „CSS active/heightened definition“ (in the `animation[]`-array), not having to replicate the former.

Comment: ...okay, it _is_ the right link.  That is indeed a heavy limitation.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **This is a bad practice** to implement/handle entire of animations with angular. *Keep it simple and let css rules do most of the things*. Just do the tricks in Angular in order to reduce lines of code, Although it can implement or handle almost everything. **In this way**, you create a custom animation (`@-webkit-keyframes`), css rules for the animation, parent, children, and just control the assignment with angular animation.

**To enhance your understanding**, just spend a little time on [Angular animation](https://angular.io/guide/animations) which describes basics. For better understanding additional methods:

- [`query`](https://angular.io/api/animations/query) finds one or more inner elements within the current
  element that is being animated within a sequence. Use with
  `animate()`
- [`transition` and `trigger`s](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers)
- And finally, [complex animation sequences](https://angular.io/guide/complex-animation-sequences)

Now lets discuss about existing problems in you code. the query selector `query('b',` works but the `animation` method used incorrectly, As you can see in [my fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xcftgh) works for a `cubic-bezier`.

In case of ordered animations, for example, animating nested elements inside parent, take advantage of [`animateChild`](https://angular.io/api/animations/animateChild) :

> Each time an animation is triggered in Angular, the parent animation
> has priority and any child animations are blocked. In order for a
> child animation to run, the parent animation must `query` each of the
> elements containing child animations, and run them using this
> function.